# ¿"Work like a charm" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, expresiones, solicitud-de-modismo

Es muy común leer en [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) comentarios del tipo:

> Thank you for your answer! The code **works like a charm**

Viniendo a decir: oye, gracias por el código que has puesto como respuesta; funciona perfectamente.

La expresión *to work like a charm* la traduce [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=charm) como *de maravilla* o *perfectamente*.

Sin embargo, dado que *charm* en sí pueden ser muchas cosas (*talismán, amuleto, atractivo, carisma, hechizo*...), me pregunto: ¿hay alguna otra expresión española que quiera decir lo mismo, de una forma idiomática?

Y añado: *perfectamente* y *de maravilla* las usamos en España; ¿se usan otras en otros países de habla hispana?

Comment: Para mí, *de maravilla* tiene connotaciones bastante parecidas a *like a charm* y es una buena traducción. Ahora bien, no sé si fuera de España se usa esta expresión o no.

Comment: Of the options you suggest _maravilla_ seems to me to come closest to the meaning I associate with the phrase (as an Anglophone).

Comment: Una variante que creo es común es _a las mil maravillas_.

Comment: En los noventa habríamos aceptado como traducción *dabuten*, esto esta dabuten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La primera opción que se me ha venido a la cabeza es:

> El código funciona de lujo.

Aunque no estoy seguro de si será demasiado propia de Andalucía. La siguiente opción fue (antes de leer los comentarios):

> El código funciona a las mil maravillas.

Otra opción incluso podría ser:

> El código va que ni pintado.

Ya si se me ocurren más iré actualizando la respuesta.

Comment: _de lujo_ también lo decimos en el nordeste de España :) Luego se me ocurrió _de fábula_

Answer (score 2):

Algunas alternativas:

- El código funciona **de maravilla**
- ... **como un relojito**
- ... **de pelos** <sub>en México</sub>
- ... **al pelo** <sub>en Colombia</sub>
- ... **como por arte de magia** (*)
- ... **como un encanto** (*)
- ... **magníficamente** (*)
- ... **que parece mentira** (*)
- ... **como Dios** (*)
- El código que has puesto como respuesta **me quedó como anillo al dedo**

(*) http://context.reverso.net/translation/english-spanish/works+like+a+charm

(*) http://www.linguee.es/ingles-espanol/traduccion/works+like+a+charm.html

Comment: Me gusta la opción de "funciona como un reloj" (en España no usaríamos el diminutivo).

Comment: Me parece que los ejemplos tomados de reverso.net parecen más hechos por un traductor automático que cosas que alguien dijera comúnmente: "como por arte de magia" significa otra cosa, y "como un encanto" es una traducción literal. Y "como anillo el dedo", si bien implica que algo funciona bien, se refiere más a la oportunidad de ese algo. "Como un relojito" solía ser común en Argentina.

Comment: @JMVanPelt "Como un encanto" literal o nó es muy usado según dice Google [18000 resultados](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22funciona+como+un+encanto%22). Similar a http://www.linguee.es/ reverso busca en toda la red tomando ejemplos de sitios que se encuentran en más de un idioma, además de subtitulos de películas. Linguee incluso provee el enlace al sitio. No es 100% confiable por lo que sólo tomé de esos sitios los que en Colombia consideraríamos frases con el mismo significado de la pregunta.

Comment: _como por arte de magia_ tal vez sea la traducción más literal de _like a charm_, si bien tiene una connotación de azar. _Como Dios_ no lo he oído, si bien en España decimos en otros contextos _como Dios manda_ para decir "bien" o "correctamente".